# call image with jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I have this really simple issue: I can't call an image with jquery. With the id of an a tag it was working. What should I change?

js:

```
$("#for_close").click(function(){
disablePopup();
});
```

html:

```
<img src="images/close-x.png" id="for_close" />
```

Is it different with images?
Thanks!

Is not working with document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#pentru_close").click(function(){
disablePopup();
});
});
```

I don't understand why this with a text works:

```
<a id="pentru_close">x</a>
```

and this not:

```
 <img src="images/close-x.png" id="pentru_close" />
```

Comment: Is your code in a $(document).ready(...) ?

Comment: What @PhilippeBoissonneault said and have you checked your disablePopup function? The code works with an alert.

Comment: The code you have shown is the correct way to bind something to the click event of any element, including images. Assuming that code either executes at the bottom of the page or resides within document.ready, it will fire disablePopup(); whenever the image is clicked. If you are not experiencing that then it is obviously something else and you are not providing us with enough information to help you. Try minimizing your setup to the bare components by removing all the noise and seeing if you can replicate what you are seeing in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Check what Philippe Boissoneault said, when the script is read while the image isn't loaded yet it won't work.

Comment: it doesn't work with document ready... so this is the right way to call images.. maybe it is something different..

Comment: solve it, I had to put a higher z-index on the image. probably the text has b default a higher z-index, I don't know...

Comment: you can only click on the top (highest z-index) layer on the page at the spot you're clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery - make sure you have added the link to your jQuery file

```
       $(document).ready(function()  {
           $("#for_close").click(function(){
            disablePopup();
            });
       });

        function disablePopup() {
         alert(' . . . ');
         }
```

HTML -

```
      <img src="images/close-x.png" id="for_close" />
```

Comment: it's better like this, but in fact the solution was to put a higher z-index on the image. probably the text has b default a higher z-index, I don't know...